# Printing an entry in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary and I am trying to get a code to print using a function.  I am having trouble getting my function to work and not understanding why it isn't printing the student from my dictionary.

```
def getstudent(key):
    students = {'23A' :['Apple', 'John', 95.6],
                '65B' :['Briton', 'Alice', 75.5],
                '56C' :['Terling', 'Mary', 98.7],
                '68R' :['Templeton', 'Alex', 90.5]}
```

I want to then run the function and type in getstudent('65B'), but when I run I don't get anything in return.

Thanks!

Comment: You aren't printing anything. You are just creating the `students` dictionary

Comment: Why use a function when you can use students.get('65B') directly

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the `key` parameter or returning anything in your function:

```
def getstudent(key):
    students = {'23A' :['Apple', 'John', 95.6],
                '65B' :['Briton', 'Alice', 75.5],
                '56C' :['Terling', 'Mary', 98.7],
                '68R' :['Templeton', 'Alex', 90.5]}
    return students.get(key) # return 

print(getstudent('65B'))
['Briton', 'Alice', 75.5]
```

Or forget about the function and just access the dict directly with `students.get(key)`.

You might also want to output an informative message if the key does not exist which can be done by passing a default value to get:

```
students.get(key,"Key does not exist")
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any error checking:

```
def getstudent(key):
    students = {'23A' :['Apple', 'John', 95.6],
                '65B' :['Briton', 'Alice', 75.5],
                '56C' :['Terling', 'Mary', 98.7],
                '68R' :['Templeton', 'Alex', 90.5]}
    print(students[key])

getstudent('65B')
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
def getstudent(key):
    students = {'23A' :['Apple', 'John', 95.6],
                '65B' :['Briton', 'Alice', 75.5],
                '56C' :['Terling', 'Mary', 98.7],
                '68R' :['Templeton', 'Alex', 90.5]}
   if key in students.keys():     # to handle if key is not present
       return students[key]
   else: return "No key found"
getstudent('65B')
```

output:

```
['Briton', 'Alice', 75.5]
```

you need to return the value

How dictionary works, dictionary has a pair that is called, `key`  and its `value`. 
The value of dictionary can be fetched by its key value. so what i am doing here. when you call a function with key. I am fetching the value based on key i.e `students[key]` it will give you value of key in your dictionary.
`students.keys()` will give you list of all key in a dictionary

Comment: you are not printing or returning the value

Answer (score 0):

```
def getstudent(key):
    students = {'23A' :['Apple', 'John', 95.6],
                '65B' :['Briton', 'Alice', 75.5],
                '56C' :['Terling', 'Mary', 98.7],
                '68R' :['Templeton', 'Alex', 90.5]}
    if key in students:
        return students[key]
    else:
        return "%s is not a valid key" % (key)
```

If you run getstudent('65B') you will get a list

['Briton', 'Alice', 75.5]

you can then access the list by indexing e.g

```
a_student = getstudent('65B')   # now a_student list is as ['Briton', 'Alice', 75.5]
print a_student[0]
```

a_student[0] prints 'Briton'